# Marking loadable kernel module as in-tree

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

*This question is about linux kernel 4.10.*

Loading an out-of-tree LKM causes kernel to print a warning:

`module: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.`

This raises from this check in [module.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/module.c#L2332):
`if (!get_modinfo(info, "intree")) {`

Reading `get_modinfo` it seams that "intree" is just a a magic-string living inside the `.ko` file.

Running `readelf` on a random LKM I found in my system shows this:

```
$ readelf -a imon.ko | grep intree
    161: 00000000000006c0     9 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   13 __UNIQUE_ID_intree1
```

While looking for `intree` in a simple, custom hello_world LKM returns no results.

Is this actually the case?

How are some modules marked as being in-tree? Is it done by adding a macro to the module (like MODULE_LICENSE), or by building the module in a specific way or something else?

Comment: Why do you want to mark an out-of-tree module as in-tree? All this is going to do is annoy kernel developers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In short, the build system contrives to add the line `MODULE_INFO(intree, "Y");` to the "*modulename*.mod.c" file if and only if the module is being built intree.

There is an obvious way to fool the system by adding that line to one of your module's regular ".c" files, but I'm not sure why you'd want to.

Longer version....

External modules are normally built with a command similar to this:

```
$ make M=`pwd` modules
```

or the old syntax:

```
$ make SUBDIRS=`pwd` modules
```

The presence of a non-empty `M` or `SUBDIRS` causes the kernel's top-level "Makefile" to set the `KBUILD_EXTMOD` variable.  It won't be set for a normal kernel build.

For stage 2 of module building (when the message  "Building modules, stage 2" is output), make runs the "scripts/Makefile.modpost" makefile.  That runs `scripts/mod/modpost` with different options when `KBUILD_EXTMOD` is set.  In particular, the `-I` option is used when `KBUILD_EXTMOD` is set.

Looking at the source for `modpost` in "scripts/mod/modpost.c", the `external_module` variable has an initial value of 0, but the `-I` option sets it to 1.  The function `add_intree_flag()` is called with the second parameter `is_intree` set to `!external_module`.  The `add_intree_flag()` function writes `MODULE_INFO(intree, "Y");` to the "*modulename*.mod.c" file if and only if its `is_intree` parameter is true.

So the difference between intree modules and external modules is the presence of the `MODULE_INFO(intree, "Y");` macro call in the "*modulename*.mod.c" file. This gets compiled to "*modulename*.mod.o" and linked with the module's other object files to form the "*modulename*.ko" file.

Comment: At a first look, this looks a little unfair to people writing perfectly open-source kernel code, but having to manage their drivers/modules out of tree. Only a few elite individuals enjoy the luxury of having their code actually in the vanilla tree. So as an "outsider", you can fudge that macro while staying out of tree, or you need to keep patching your local copy of the upstream vanilla tree. AFAIR, a tainted kernel is deprived of some debugging features...

Comment: OR, THEN AGAIN, there is another way of looking at this: maybe the Linux leaders do want you to get used to the GIT. To maintain your own local branch, and instead of publishing a tarball, you ask an upstream maintainer to include your code, by sending a pull request...